I can't seem to be able to upload a file using SeaweedFS with Axios but works with curl
I am trying to use SeaweedFS to handle my file uploads in my Nest.js back-end application and i have correctly set up SeaweedFS and I have uploaded files and fetched them successfullly using my terminal but I can't seem to get it to work from the back-end application. In the code, below, I can get the fid successfully using the first axios post request but using that fid to upload the file is not working as it is returning : "Error: socket hang up".
async uploadFile(file : Express.Multer.File) : Promise<string> {

        const form = new FormData();
        form.append('file', file.buffer, file.originalname);

        const response = await axios.default.post(`${this.masterServerUrl}/dir/assign`, form, {
          headers: form.getHeaders(),
        });
    
        const { fid } = response.data;
 
        const uploadUrl = `${this.volumeServerUrl}/${fid}`;

        await axios.default.post(uploadUrl, form, {
          headers: {
            ...form.getHeaders(), 
          },
          
        });
    
        return fid;
    }

I tried changing the content-type to multiple different values but it does not work.
